# Terminal: List only and specifically, the 5th file in a directory

Tags: terminal, file

I am wondering if there is a Terminal command which will specifically list the 5th file in a directory. I was initially using the `ls | head -5` command to complete this, however it listed all other files as well as the fifth, an action which is undesirable for the purpose i have in mind for the proposed command.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `head`, use the `tail` command:

```
ls | head -5 | tail -n 1
```

where the `-n 1` argument displays the last line of the input.

For more info on the command, type `man tail` in Terminal.